# Can we conclude that Peano's axioms consistent from soundness?

Tags: logic, model-theory, peano-axioms

One of the corollaries of soundness says that if $\Gamma$ is satisfiable, then $\Gamma$ is consistent. I am wondering whether we can conclude that Peano's axioms $\mathsf{PA}$ is consistent from the fact that the standard model of arithmetic $\mathcal{M}_A=(\mathbb N, 0^{\mathcal{M}_A}, s^{\mathcal{M}_A}, +^{\mathcal{M}_A}, \times^{\mathcal{M}_A}, <^{\mathcal{M}_A})$ satisfies $\mathsf{PA}$? Perhaps not?

Comment: The standard model is in set theory, which we do not know is consistent.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews It's reasonable to be skeptical about whether set theory is consistent, but this doesn't change the fact that consistency of PA is a theorem (of set theory). This would be like replying to "Is the Poincaré conjecture true?" by "Well, the proof is carried out in set theory, and we don't know set theory is consistent..."

Comment: @AlexKruckman That answers the question if you assume set theory, but, of course, the title doesn't mention set theory, and "Does this mean Peano is consistent" doesn't mention set theory. But sure, since set theory is practically designed to include Peano, if we assume  set theory is consistent, then Peano is consistent. We don't even need any general theorem - if we could find an inconsistency in n Peano, we'd easily translate it into an inconsistency of set theor.y.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Set theory is the default background foundation of mathematics. If someone asks you a question about group theory, do you say "well, that's true if you assume set theory..."?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews The argument in your last comment shows $\mathrm{Con}(ZF)\to \mathrm{Con}(PA)$. This is different from the OP's question, which is about $\mathrm{Con}(PA)$ itself. And the fact is that $\mathrm{Con}(PA)$ is a theorem! Your conditional theorem $\mathrm{Con}(ZF)\to \mathrm{Con}(PA)$ has the benefit of being provable in a much weaker meta-theory. But the question does not mention the meta-theory, so my default assumption is that we're working in ordinary mathematics, I.e., we have all the tools of ZFC at our disposal.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, absolutely. It is a theorem that $\mathsf{PA}$ is consistent. The easiest way to prove this theorem is to exhibit $\mathbb{N}$ as a model of $\mathsf{PA}$.